# How to I find the relationship of ciphertext and plaintext that are encrypted by AES 256 CTR

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

Given that
plaintext = FD3CD3D5E10EB80F91670EC907840FD08F63F0CC8CD8BEBC86A858A5494A6BAC
ciphertext = 5D4221C6D1F931529C4C852E310338CCAD71C9547A7B42039084D67F89794DD2

Is it possible to find the key or iv if the iv is generated using $openssl rand -hex 16?

Comment: This is not a programming question, but no, you cannot.

Comment: This is called a known-plaintext attack. A cryptosystem where this is possible would be deeply insecure. (Luckily AES-CTR does not have this problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Even if you know the plaintext, what you could find is the
`E(nonce+counter)` (IV = Nonce + Counter) which is the IV encrypted.

Generally IV is not a secret and most often is given at the beginning or at the end of the ciphertext.

Comment: What about another ciphertext where it is encrypted using the same iv as the information above? is it possible to solve it?

Comment: Check the AES CTR model here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4d/CTR_encryption_2.svg/601px-CTR_encryption_2.svg.png

Let's say that the `block cipher encryption` block is something like hashing (it's not, but to make it simple we accept that)

Whatever gets in this block, is not possible to recover it (except if you do have the key).

So even if you reuse the same IV once or multiple times,
If you just know ciphertext and plaintext, what you get is the hashed IV.